# How to debug Electron.net when app is stuck on loading screen

Tags: electron.net

I had an issue where I was unable to run `electronize start` and begin the debug process, but I was able to get it going when I deleted the bin and obj folders and then ran the command. I don't know why this worked, but it did. Now I'm trying to build my app and when I run the .exe it loads up the splash screen and then it just hangs, similar to how it did before. I do not know where to begin debugging this, i'm not sure where to even go for error messages or anything. Where can I begin to look?

I ran `electronize build /target win` and tried running from the /bin/Desktop folder. I also just installed it and tried running it from the installed .exe, same thing happens, it just hangs at the splash screen.

Could it be port mismatch? As in Electron listens on one port and the dotnet app is on another? How would I confirm that?